# "I get my paycheck on the last day of the month" -> Does this imply I get a physical check?

Tags: meaning

Stemming from a discussion I recently had, does this statement imply that the payment I receive is physically a check? Or is it perfectly naturally to use for a situation where my payment is received entirely electronically?

Comment: "I get my paycheck" is now generally used to mean "I get paid" so it denotes the action rather than the literal method.

Comment: Likewise you can dial a number even though (almost) no one has a working rotary phone, and you can tune in even though television is digital now.

Answer (score 1):

It does *imply* it, but one would be foolish to take this literally without clarification, since it is much more common nowadays to receive payment electronically.

To state the same without the implication of a physical check, one would simply say “I get paid on the last day of the month”.